# Bootstrap 4 carousel not working in laravel 5.8 project

Tags: bootstrap-4, laravel-5.8

I have a laravel project (v5.8) and i use the default bootstrap 4 that ship with it for my frontend css framework. Everything is working like a charm except the godless carousel. I suspect it has to be with how laravel compile the assets with mix because if i create a blade view using the CDN version of bootstrap, jquery, etc. the carousel works. But if i use the app.js, that laravel mix generates, the images stack on top of each other. But the weirdest part is that the carousel kind of "work" because the stacked images do slide, for example, initially it shows me the three stacked in this order "40.jpg", "41.jpg" and "42.jpg", then slide and at top is "41.jpg" and below "42.jpg" and finally when slides it shows me "42.jpg" alone and the process start again with the three images.

Here is my code of each part:

/resources/views/test.blade.php:

```
    @extends ('layouts.web')

@section('content')

    <div class="container">

        <div id="myCar" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="http://localhost:81/witinea/storage/public/img/gallery/general/40.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Imagen 40">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="http://localhost:81/witinea/storage/public/img/gallery/general/41.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Imagen 41">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="http://localhost:81/witinea/storage/public/img/gallery/general/42.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Imagen 42">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCar" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCar" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>

@endsection

@section('footerScripts')

    @parent


@endsection
```

In layouts.web i define my header, footer, menu, the links to my style, scripts, etc.

/resources/js/app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');

import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
```

/resources/js/bootstrap.js:

```
window._ = require('lodash');

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

And finally, i compile my assets with laravel mix and webpack:

/webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
mix.setPublicPath('public');
mix.setResourceRoot('../');
```

I can't find where the issue is. Bootstrap is loading correctly, in my opinion, because i have used classes of bootstrap for my menu, header, layout grid. I think that jquery is also loading correctly because i have a "go to top" arrow that hides/shows when scrolling using jquery. So i am totally lost, i cannot find why the images are stacking on top of each other.

Sorry for the large post but as i am unable to identify where could be the problem i tried to be the most specific i can. Thank you for your help.

EDIT: I forgot to include the source code of the page generated by laravel, maybe there the error is more evident:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="Fp766WwnOt1vKyUE4fe7bYsRk0VNtBhRQYBmSKfN">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

    <title>#</title>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/apple-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/apple-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/apple-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/android-icon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/manifest.json">
    <link rel="icon" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">


        <script>
        </script>



        <link href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="return-to-top"><i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
    <header>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <nav id="main" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top navbar-custom">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/index.php" class="navbar-brand"><img src="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/img/witinea_logo.png" width="313" height="100" class="img-fluid"></a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#w0-collapse" aria-controls="w0-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div id="w0-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul id="w1" class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item h5 font-weight-bold"><a class="nav-link active text-primary" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/index.php#QuienesSomos">Quiénes Somos</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item h5 font-weight-bold"><a class="nav-link text-primary" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/index.php#Servicios">Nuestros Servicios</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item h5 font-weight-bold"><a class="nav-link text-primary" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/index.php#Clientes">Clientes</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item h5 font-weight-bold"><a class="nav-link text-primary" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/index.php/galeria">Galerías</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item h5 font-weight-bold"><a class="nav-link text-primary" href="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/index.php#Contacto">Contáctanos</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul id="w2" class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item h4"><a class="nav-link text-info" href="https://www.facebook.com/ConsultoresWitinea/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f "></i></a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item h4"><a class="nav-link text-info" href="" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>

    <div class="container">

        <div id="myCar" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="http://localhost:81/witinea/storage/public/img/gallery/general/40.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Imagen 40">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="http://localhost:81/witinea/storage/public/img/gallery/general/41.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Imagen 41">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="http://localhost:81/witinea/storage/public/img/gallery/general/42.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Imagen 42">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCar" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCar" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>






    </main>

    <footer class="bg-secondary">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-5 small text-light">
                    Copyright © 2019 
                    <a class="text-light pl-2" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f "></i></a>
                    <a class="text-light pl-2" href="" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>



        <script src="http://localhost:81/witinea/public/js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) {        // If page is scrolled more than 50px
                    $('#return-to-top').fadeIn(200);    // Fade in the arrow
                } else {
                    $('#return-to-top').fadeOut(200);   // Else fade out the arrow
                }
            });

            $('#return-to-top').click(function() {      // When arrow is clicked
                $('body,html').animate({
                    scrollTop : 0                       // Scroll to top of body
                }, 500);
            });

        </script>





</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I found the problem. I am an idiot. The problem is that i added some custom styles to my main CSS that collision with the classes of the carousel.

Comment: feel free to delete your question